# How to override all of the CSS for a specific element?

Tags: css

I have a button which is from the bootstrap class; I want to add my CSS to the button too; but it seems that padding of bootstrap overrides my CSS! How can I override the CSS of Bootstrap in this case!

Also it iow sorth mentioning that I could override the bootstrap CSS by putting the CSS inline! But thats not what I what to do! Is there any better way that I can have my CSS in my seperate file and override the CSS of bootstrap in this cas (padding,...)

If you need more clarification, please let me know!

PS: I dont want to change the padding of CSS for the btn class either!

ADDED:
myCSS:

```
.delete_btn{
    width: 50px;
font-size: 8px;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
top: -7px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;

}
```

my button:

```
<button id='images[i]['url']' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete_btn' >Delete</button>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please show your code. It's likely that the problem is specificity, i.e. that one selector is more specific than the other and is therefore overriding it.

Comment: You can use `!important` but if it isn't overriding the default bootstrap css, your tag is not specific enough. Are you including the CSS after bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take some actions to override the style:

- One be sure your CSS is loaded after the bootstrap.
- Two write your class at the end of the file.
- Three you can make more specific your selector with an id  like `id="button"` or descendent selectors like

  ```
   #container .myButtonClass {
         padding:0px;
   }
  ```

You can check more about priority of CSS definitions [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/) and [here](http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/css-types.php)

Answer (score -1):

Use 'important' in your CSS.

For example:
You want your padding size not bootstrap provided size, then

```
.yourClass{

   padding:10px !important;

 }
```

Or

```
 #parentElement .yourClass{
 padding:10px;

}
```

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to use `!important`. Its use normally reveals code in need of refactoring.

Comment: But it is one of the solution for the above question by using plain CSS and not Java Script

Comment: Yes, in a sense. But the best solution would be to refactor the CSS in such a way that `!important` is unnecessary. It is *a* solution, but it probably isn't an optimal one.

Answer (score -1):

Add id to the element and then apply your padding. Ids have higher specificity than classes.

Comment: You see where you are using `.delete_btn` in your css? In order for your styles to override bootstrap styling, you need to use id (id specificity 100 vs class specificity 10) to target the button element. Also, your id shouldn't look like `images[i]['url']` --> brackets and quotes are not allowed in ids. Use `id="danko_button_override"` or something like that and then use `#danko_button_override` selector in your css and you should be good.